# Apk name that will be visible to final play store users

Tags: java, android, mobile, kotlin

I have an android studio projects that has an original package name com.example.app1 and obviously the name that shows up below the icon of my app when i install in order to debug is App 1. I have finished the app, though i don't want the users to see that name (App 1) when they install my app from the play store on their phone and on the unisnstall menu. I just want them to see Awesome App or something. I do not nececerily need to change the package name, only the name that the users will see on their devices. What can i do? Set an applicationId different from my package name or change the whole package name by refactoring?

Comment: It's whatever name you define for the launcher. The package is irrelevant. For the app store itself, it's defined in the store entry.

Comment: Sorry i did not get that. I am new to android an i am having difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:label="My awesome app"` in Manifest for your application

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.MyApp"           
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```